# Set rounded corner on QLabel displaying an image

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Im trying to set a rounded corner on a `QLabel`. The `QLabel` is loaded from an URL like so:

```
QByteArray jpegData = reply->readAll();
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.loadFromData(jpegData);

pixmap = pixmap.scaled(150, 150, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
ui->agentPicture->setPixmap(pixmap);
ui->agentPicture->setStyleSheet("border:2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px;background-color: transparent;");
```

For some reason its only the border that gets rounded.

Any ideas?

Comment: background-color: transparent; probably because of this. I think you don't need to load image from code, you just set it in your style sheet as a background image

Comment: I have to load the image from the code :/

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/23786708/6165833